# How do I hook up UICollectionViewController in UIContainerView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have an app that looks like this:

[image: Storyboard]

`ViewController` is the parent VC into which I placed 3 container view controllers.
I subclassed `UIViewController` for all three, Top, Mid & BottomContainerViewControllers.

Here is my question.  I want the `BottomVC` to have a `UICollectionView` which scrolls sideways.  So I added a `UICollectionView` as you can see (gave it a nice greenish background).

But my question is, how do I hook this up?

This is my BottomContainerViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BottomContainerViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

And the .m file has the following methods:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But when I run it I get:

```
[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "qcP-Hl-Txn-view-aJq-Dc-875" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
```

The `UICollectionView` outlet is connected.  What else could be the problem?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you did here. If you have a UICollectionViewController, it comes with a collection view that is its self.view -- you shouldn't add a collection view or need to make an outlet, the controller has a self.collectionView property just like a table view controller has a self.tableView.

Comment: No, the BottomContainerViewController was originally a UIViewController.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it was originally -- your code shows now that BottomContainerViewController is a subclass of UICollectionViewController. If you changed that, you might want to just delete that class and start over.

Comment: @rdelmar why would i want to delete that class and start over? Dont I want a UICollectioViewController subclass to manage the UICollectionView in it?

Comment: I was thinking something got messed up if BottomContainerViewController was originally a UIViewController and you changed it to a UICollectionViewController as you implied in your comment. If that's not the case, then ignore my comment. I'm confused now about what you've actually done.

Comment: @rdelmar I actually sorta followed your advice and it worked. I changed the BottomVC parent class from UICollectionViewController to UIViewController in the header.  Now i need to know why because I was obviously misunderstanding this. I had a UIViewController named BottomVC. I changed its parent class from UIViewController to UICollectionViewController in the header. Then I dragged a UICollectionView outlet and connected it & added both methods mentioned above to the .m file. Why

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on -- you should be able to use a UICollectionViewController. If you do, you don't need to add the collectionView or make an outlet, it comes with one.

Comment: It didnt come with a UICollectionView because I didnt drag in a UICollectionViewController into the bottom. I dragged in a UIContainer and made that container's vc a BottomContainerViewController which was a UIViewController subclass to begin with.

Comment: @rdelmar - the question is clear.  you should be able to drag in a UICollectionView and then "make it work", exactly as you can drag in a table view, and "make it work".  You certainly don't "have to use" the table view controller convenience setup in IB.

Comment: @JoeBlow, I didn't say the question was unclear, I was unclear about what he actually did. The BottomContainerViewController is a subclass of UICollectionViewController (not a UIViewController as he says in the text) so there should have been no need to drag in a collection view or set up an outlet. It should have worked fine with a UICollectionViewController despite the accepted answer.

Comment: @rdelmar - I guess .. I didn't understand that :)  thanks... (Related UICollectionView question, for anyone reading .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790601/uikit-dynamics-exactly-like-iphone-text-messages-ready-solution )  Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a uiviewcontroller class to manage the bottom container. Link as you normally would using that view controller.  Connect delegate, datasource, implement the delegate and data source... etc...

Comment: why does it have to be a UIViewController and not a UICollectionViewController?

Comment: That's what i don't get !

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, this is what worked for me:
1: Click the "Show Document Outline" button in the bottom left of your storyboard.
2: Find "Bottom Container View" which should be a subclass of UICollectionViewController
3: Cut the subviews of the highest level view (Everything you see from expanding the first view)
4: Delete that primary view and paste back in your collection view

Essentially, the top view has to be a UICollectionView and not the usual UIView that is defaulted by putting the Container into the storyboard.