# Collectionview Controller vs Collectionview

Tags: ios

I'm beginner at IOS.  I don't quite understand what is difference between collection view and collecionviewcontroller and in what cases can I use each of them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView` (just another UIView)

`UICollectionViewController` inherits from `UIViewController`..
and it implements some protocols.. like UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource .. it means everything is already done for you.. and you just have to use it.. but as everything is already done for you.. you may not be able to do some stuff.. like resizing your collectionView ..

if you want full control I recommend you to use your own UIViewController.. and add a UICollectionView as a subview.. so you can place it wherever you want and resize it.. don't forget to implement UICollectionView protocols for delegation and datasource :)

Answer (score 1):

It's based on your requirements. You may change some properties with your View controllers. But when you use as part of its' controllers, you can't change it.

```
For example you Can´t change UICollectionView Size of UICollectionViewController.
```

In these case, you must use UICollectionView in viewcontroller. As like this, if you want to customize some property but functionality are same in all.

Here I mention some ref for you: [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626495/how-do-i-hook-up-uicollectionviewcontroller-in-uicontainerview)

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewController is specialized in managing UICollectionView. Collection view controller is inherited from UIViewController specifically for collection views so if collection views are removed then there is no use for Collection view controller.

Having said that,collection views can be used inside UIViewController whereas UIView can't be added inside UICollectionViewController.